# How to delete struct object in go?

Tags: go, struct

Let's say I have the following struct:

```
type Person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}
```

If I make an object of that struct

```
person1 := Person{name: "Name", age: 69}
```

If I set this object to nil

```
person1 = nil
```

it doesn't work, in fact it's a type assignment error, but it works for maps and slices. So, how otherwise would I remove the object i.e deallocate? I looked at the documentation for delete builtin but it removes an entry from a given map. Thanks.

Comment: Each element of such a variable or value is set to the zero value for its type: false for booleans, 0 for integers, 0.0 for floats, "" for strings, and nil for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Go is a garbage collected language. You are not supposed to, and you cannot delete objects from memory. It is the garbage collector's *duty* and *responsibility* to do so, and it does this *automatically*. The garbage collector will properly remove objects from memory when they become unreachable.

You can assign `nil` to maps and slices because `nil` is a valid value (the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)) for those types. The zero value for `struct` types is not `nil` but a `struct` value where all its fields have their zero values.

If you want to clear or overwrite the struct value, you may simply [assign](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) another struct value to it, preferably the zero value (an empty struct):

```
person1 := Person{name: "Name", age: 69}
// work with person1

// Clear person1:
person1 = Person{}
```

But know that this will not free memory allocated by `person1`; as wrote earlier, it will be freed automatically by the GC when it becomes unreachable.

`nil` is also a valid value (the zero value) for pointer types, so if `person1` would be a pointer to `Person` (that is, `*Person`), you could also assign `nil` to it, e.g.:

```
person1 := &Person{name: "Name", age: 69}
// work with person1

// Clear person1:
person1 = nil
```

When clearing a pointer by setting it to `nil`, the pointed object–again–will be taken care of by the GC.

For more details about how the garbage collector works, see [Cannot free memory once occupied by bytes.Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382600/golang-cannot-free-memory-once-occupied-by-bytes-buffer/37383604#37383604).

Comment: @mkmayank If you want to clear the receiver, it must be a pointer, and assign an empty struct to the pointed value.

Comment: It’s dumb that you can’t if you want to.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to set nil use pointer instead of value.

```
person1 := &Person{name: "Name", age: 69}
// Then you can set
person1 = nil
```