# Delete or resize array in go

Tags: arrays, go

I need delete or resize isPrime array after CalRange func called (isPrime=nil not working)

```
isPrime := [size]bool{}
CalRange(size, maxİndex, isPrime[:])
isPrime = nil
```

Thanks all for answers
I solve it like that. [How to delete struct object in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066797/how-to-delete-struct-object-in-go/42067048#42067048)

```
person1 := &Person{name: "Name", age: 69}
// work with person1
// Clear person1:
person1 = nil
```

Comment: `[size]bool{}` is not a good idea, because the type of `isPrime` changes, when the value of `size` changes.

Comment: Use a slice instead of an array.

Comment: _"not working"_? Can you show expected and actual results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go, arrays are different from slices. Slices can be nil, but arrays can't, since they are static.

In your code above, on the line 1, the contents of `isPrime` are actually `[false false false ...]` with as many false values as your size variable allows.

Thus, your array can't really be deleted or resized. It can only be zero-valued.

If you really need to resize it, I recommend using slices instead, or creating a new array with the new size and copying the previous array's contents into it.

Answer (score 1):

Go is a garbage collected language, you can't delete objects from memory, you can only "clear" them. For details, see [How to delete struct object in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066797/how-to-delete-struct-object-in-go/42067048#42067048) You also can't resize an array, an array is of fixed size (and the size is part of the type).

To clear an array, you may assign its [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) to it (which is not `nil`). Use a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) for a zero-value array, like `[size]bool{}`:

```
const size = 4
isPrime := [size]bool{true, true}
fmt.Println(isPrime)

isPrime = [size]bool{}
fmt.Println(isPrime)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kT-lLZu4lCK)):

```
[true true false false]
[false false false false]
```