# How to release memory allocated by a slice?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    storage := []string{}

    for i := 0; i < 50000000; i++ {
        storage = append(storage, "string string string string string string string string string string string string")
    }

    fmt.Println("done allocating, emptying")

    storage = storage[:0]
    storage = nil

    for {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

The code above will allocate about ~30mb of memory, and then won't release it. Why is that? How can I force go to release memory used by this slice? I sliced that slice and then nilled it.

The program I'm debugging is a simple HTTP input buffer: it appends all requests into large chunks, and sends these chunks over a channel to goroutine for processing. But problem is illustrated above - I can't get storage to release the memory and then eventually run out of memory.

Edit: as some people pointed out to similar [question](https://deferpanic.com/blog/manual-memory-management-in-go/), no, it first doesn't work, second isn't what I'm asking for. The slice gets emptied, the memory does not.

Comment: Nope, this isn't what I'm looking for. I can get the slice emptied, but I need it to release the memory.

Comment: @Filmzy, thank you. I've updated my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "release the memory"? If you mean hand the memory back to the operating system that's usually not done. If you mean make the memory available to other allocations in your program, then that's done.

Comment: I ran your program for like 5..10 minutes, and memory was released back to OS. When I inserted a `debug.FreeOSMemory()` call before the last `for` loop, memory again was released back to OS without waiting. So this is a duplicate of [Cannot free memory once occupied by bytes.Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382600/cannot-free-memory-once-occupied-by-bytes-buffer/37383604#37383604).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several things going on here.

The first one which is needed to be absorbed is that Go is
a garbage-collected language; the actual algorithm of its GC
is mostly irrelevant but one aspect of it is crucial to understand:
it does not use reference counting, and hence there's no way to
somehow make the GC immediately reclaim the memory of any given
value whose storage is allocated on the heap.
To recap it in more simple words, it's futile to do

```
s := make([]string, 10*100*100)
s = nil
```

as the second statement will indeed remove the sole reference
to the slice's underlying memory but won't make the GC go
and "mark" that memory as available for reuse.

This means two things:

- You should know how the GC works.
  [This](https://golang.org/s/go15gcpacing) explains how it works
  since v1.5 and up until now (v1.10 these days).
- You should structure those of your algorythms which are
  memory-intensive in a way that reduces memory pressure.

The latter can be done in several ways:

- Preallocate, when you have a sensible idea about how much to.

  In your example, you start with a slice of length 0,
  and then append to it a lot. Now, almost all library code which deals
  with growing memory buffers—the Go runtime included—deals with these
  allocations by 1) allocating *twice* the memory requested—hoping to
  prevent several future allocations, and 2) *copies* the "old" contents
  over, when it had to reallocate. This one is important: when reallocation
  happens, it means there's *two* memory regions now: the old one and the new
  one.

  If you can estimate that you may need to hold `N` elements on
  average, preallocate for them using `make([]T, 0, N)`—
  more info [here](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)
  and [here](https://blog.golang.org/slices).
  If you'll need to hold less than `N` elements, the tail of that buffer
  will be unused, and if you'll need to hold more than `N`, you'll need
  to reallocate, but on average, you won't need any reallocations.
- Re-use your slice(s). Say, in your case, you could "reset" the slice
  by reslicing it to the zero length and then use it again for the next
  request. This is called "pooling", and in the case of mass-parallel access
  to such a pool, you could use `sync.Pool` to hold your buffers.
- *Limit the load on your system* to make the GC be able to cope with
  the sustained load. A good overview of the two approaches to such
  limiting is [this](http://ferd.ca/queues-don-t-fix-overload.html).

Comment: This is incredible information, thank you.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov, there was an error in preallocation example—should have been `make([]T, 0, N)`, sorry. Added further pointers to the docs about how slices work.

Answer (score 2):

In the program you wrote, it makes no sense to release memory because no part of code is requesting it any more.

To make a valid case, you have to request a new memory and release it inside the loop. Then you will observe that the memory consumption will stabilize at some point.

Comment: Well, yes, It isn't actual program of course. This is part of actual code: `func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
 uris = append(uris, string(ctx.RequestURI()[:]))
}` and then in go routine `go func() {
  for {
   time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
   if len(uris) > 0 {
    metrics <- uris
    uris = uris[:0]
   }
  }
 }()` And under benchmarking tests I always run out of memory quite fast.

Comment: I've updated my question, to make it more reality-based.

Comment: @AleksandrMakov And now the answer makes no sense. Please add another question.