# CSV Upload Memory Usage Stacking

Tags: csv, go

I have an application that a user can upload .CSV files too, the API will read the .CSV file and for each row determine if it needs to be inserted into the database.

I loop over these rows in the CSV and add the items to a slice, once the slice size hits 500, I run a GORM CreateInBatches method and then wipe the slice.

My issue is that the memory usage is stacking for each file that the user uploads, and I have narrowed it down to an issue with the slice and resetting it.

I initialise a slice and I will be wiping this slice at 500.

```
insertMain := make([]*models.MainEntry, 0)
```

I then loop over the .CSV

```
for {
  row, err := parser.Read()
  if err == io.EOF {
    break
  }
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

  if (len(insertMain) >= 500) {
    u.db.CreateInBatches(insertMain, 500)
    insertMain = nil
  }

  // Processing happens here to determine if the row needs to be inserted.

  // If the row needs to be inserted this is how I add it to the slice

  entity := &models.MainEntry{
    SettlementDate:                      &date,
    SettlementPeriod:                    &period,
    Zone:                                &zone
  }

  insertMain = append(insertMain, entity)
}
```

The reason I know its the slice causing an issue is that if I remove the `.append` part of the code so nothing gets added. The memory usage is not used at all.

How can I wipe the slice and remove all elements from the memory when 500 items has been hit?

Comment: `make([]*models.MainEntry, 0)` this doesn't initialise the slice with a capacity of 550 though?

Comment: @maksimov yeah sorry I edited the question. I am unable to initialise the slice with 550 as the IF check will always fire.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to release memory allocated by a slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618201/how-to-release-memory-allocated-by-a-slice)

Comment: How the memory usage looks like when you call `u.db.CreateInBatches(insertMain, 500)` multiple times with the same data? I'm curious if this not the source of the "leak"