# Memory not being released back to OS

Tags: go, vips

I've created an image resizing server that creates a few different thumbnails of and image that you upload to it. I'm using the package https://github.com/h2non/bimg for resizing, which is using libvips with c-bindings.

Before going to production I've started to stress test my app with jmeter and upload 100 images to it concurrently for a few times after each other and noticed that the memory is not being released back to the OS.

To illustrate the problem I've written a few lines of code that reads 100 images and resize them (without saving them anywhere) and then waits for 10 minutes. It repeats like this for 5 times

My code and memory/CPU graph can be found here:
https://github.com/hamochi/bimg-memory-issue

It's clear that the memory is being reused for ever cycle, otherwise it should have doubled (I think). But it's never released back to the OS.

Is this a general behaviour for cgo? Or bimg that is doing something weird. Or is it just my code that is faulty?

Thank you very much for any help you can give!

Comment: Are you sure it's the Go program that uses the memory? Does that usage include filesystem caches, for instance? Do you know how that's measured? What does top show?

Comment: Yes I'm measuring it with Top as well, as we speak the process is still using 38.2% according to top. It's the same case when I monitor it with docker stats and running it inside a container. I've added at screenshot of top in my repo.

Comment: Related, does this explain it? [Cannot free memory once occupied by bytes.Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382600/cannot-free-memory-once-occupied-by-bytes-buffer/37383604#37383604)

Comment: I've read that post before, and decided to change bimg to a pure a go image resizing library (which is ways more memory demanding than libvips). And as the post explained, the memory was released back to the os eventually, and I could also force it with debug.FreeOSMemory(). 

This is not the case with bimg, so that's why I'm asking if this is general cgo behaviour.

Comment: CGO behavior is the same as C. Have you tried freeing the cache that vips uses?

Comment: There are three functions the library offers, bimg.VipsCacheSetMaz, bimg.VipsCacheSetMaxMem and bimg.VipsCacheDropAll. I've used them all, and also there is a handy function for displaying memory info stats from libvips. It displays: {Memory:0 MemoryHighwater:6407072309 Allocations:0}.

Comment: @hamochi, do you solve the problem, we are having a similiar problem, I'm not sure whether it's caused by vips, pprof shows the memory usage is ok, but the system report the memory is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

There's a libvips thing to track and debug reference counts -- you could try enabling that and see if you have any leaks.

https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/libvips-vips.html#vips-leak-set

Though from your comment above about bimg memory stats, it sounds like it's probably all OK.

It's easy to test libvips memory from Python. I made this small  program:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pyvips
import sys

# disable libvips operation caching ... without this, it'll cache all the
# thumbnail operations and we'll just be testing the jpg write
pyvips.cache_set_max(0)

for i in range(0, 10000):
    print("loop {} ...".format(i))
    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        # thumbnail to fit 128x128 box
        image = pyvips.Image.thumbnail(filename, 128)
        thumb = image.write_to_buffer(".jpg")
```

ie. repeatedly thumbnail a set of source images. I ran it like this:

```
$ for i in {1..100}; do cp ~/pics/k2.jpg $i.jpg; done
$ ../fing.py *
```

And watched RES in top. I saw:

```
loop | RES (kb)
  -- | --
 100 | 39220
 250 | 39324
 300 | 39276
 400 | 39316
 500 | 39396
 600 | 39464
 700 | 39404
1000 | 39420
```

As long as you have no refcount leaks, I think what you are seeing is expected behaviour. Linux processes can only release pages at the end of the heap back to the OS (have a look at the brk and sbrk sys calls):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbrk

Now imagine if 1) libvips allocates 6GB, 2) the Go runtime allocates 100kb, 3) libvips releases 6GB. Your libc (the thing in your process that will call sbrk and brk on your behalf) can't hand the 6GB back to the OS because of the 100kb alloc at the end of the heap. Some malloc implementations have better memory fragmentation behaviour than others, but the default linux one is pretty good.

In practice, it doesn't matter. malloc will reuse holes in your memory space, and even if it doesn't, they will get paged out anyway under memory pressure and won't end up eating RAM. Try running your process for a few hours, and watch RES. You should see it creep up, but then stabilize.

(I'm not at all a kernel person, the above is just my understanding, corrections very welcome of course)

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. I will run my process for a few hours and see how it goes. I'd wished it freed back the memory to the OS, because that would help me scale upp my service easier, but I there are other ways to work around that. Libvips is still so ridiculously fast and memory efficient compared to other libraries and I will stick to it for sure.

Comment: I ran my process longer, for 17 hours. First time the memory increased until it crashed. The second time it was more stable, it increase to 78% and was around there until it stopped resizing (17 hours later) and dropped to around 65%. It seems stable enough, I just have to make sure it restarts in case it crashes again.

Comment: I added a py program to show libvips memuse. I see a steady 40mb or so here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the resize code:

```
_, err = bimg.NewImage(buffer).Resize(width, height)
```

The image is gobject and need unref explicitly to release the memory, try:

```
image, err = bimg.NewImage(buffer).Resize(width, height)
defer C.g_object_unref(C.gpointer(image))
```